# allowEdit in Ionic Camera plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I want to upload picture by writing some text on it before saving the image.
There is one option in Camera plugin to edit images i.e. “allowEdit”.But it is not allowing me to edit/annotate image (no option is coming to perform this) when I am taking an image in my iOS device (iPad). Is there any other option to do this in ionic.

I am using the following code to take picture.

```
  let option: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 100,
  targetWidth: 900,
  targetHeight: 600,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
  allowEdit: true,
  sourceType: 1
  // saveToPhotoAlbum: false
}

this.camera.getPicture(option).then((imageURI) => {

});
```

Comment: I saw this on cordova documentation                                                    "On iOS passing PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY or PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM along with DestinationType.NATIVE_URI will disable any image modifications (resize, quality change, cropping, etc.) due to implementation specific." 

I am not using either of this still no option is coming for image editing or not even my default photo-editor is coming.

Answer (score 0):

PhotoEditor SDK + Cordova & Ionic – imgly
https://blog.photoeditorsdk.com/photoeditor-sdk-cordova-dabe146e6c13
Jun 14, 2017 - The idea is to create a Cordova app that allows the user to open an image from their photo library and edit this image using the PhotoEditor SDK on iOS and Android. ... Therefore we adapted a resolveDependencies.js script from StackOverflow that uses node-xcode to configure the project correctly during plugin installation.